# Odoo 12 - File Content missing in ir.attachment

Tags: odoo, attachment, odoo-12

In Odoo 12, We are using ir.attachment to store JSON files. In some of the attachments, the file content is missing somehow. File size, Stored Filename, and Mime type are still there and we're keeping condition if there is a JSON file, only then we're creating ir.attachment records. It is just file content(datas) is empty somehow for some of the records.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Method we're following to create attachment:

```py
def create_attachment(self, file_name=False, file=False):

    if file and file_name:
        file = base64.encodestring(file)
        attachment_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
            'name': file_name,
            'datas': file,
            'datas_fname': file_name,
            'type': 'binary',
            'res_model': 'res.partner',
            'res_id': self.id,
         })
```

Comment: How did you call that function?

Answer (score 1):

The thing it's that if some records are created with content and others not, that means that your attachment creation code it's ok.

You need to check the code that produce the JSON file content and check if you are really getting the proper data values for the attachment creation.

Or you are saying that the content of those files dissappear after a while?
Also you can go directly to the filestore db folder and check the file that it's located at the `store_fname` location inside the filestore db folder

The filestore location it's controlled by the odoo config option `data_dir` with a default value `~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/` relative to the local user home folder in Linux. Could have another value in a different OS

Comment: I checked the filestore db folder. but didn't find any file located with store_fname and also content aren't missing after a while. It's missing at the time of attachment creation.
Another thing is we've two instance for our project and this issue is happening only one of the instance.

Comment: So pretty that's the issue. If you have 2 odoo instances for the same db you need to have a shared filestore, otherwise the file will be physically created on the one that have received and processed the request

Comment: Also there are several other issues that you could face when you cluster odoo with several instances. It's the normal navigation slow? How it's configured to work with 2 instances?

Comment: These are two separate instance with separate db. Nothing is shared between them.

Comment: Ok. I have misunderstood the 2 instances part. You need to check then that the file content is not empy before creating the attachment